Laravel Project with LiteSpeed LSCACHE: How to Exclude Admin Bar from Cache for Authenticated Users?
I'm working on a Laravel project that utilizes LiteSpeed LSCACHE. I’ve encountered an issue where, when the cache is enabled for visitors, authenticated users are also served the visitor cache. This leads to problems, as the logged-in users do not see their custom admin bar and face issues with CSRF tokens.
I noticed that in WordPress, when LiteSpeed Cache is active, it serves public cache to visitors and private cache to authenticated users, allowing user-specific components like the admin bar to be displayed correctly. However, I couldn't find any resources for Laravel that explain how to achieve a similar setup without using Edge Side Includes (ESI), which are not supported by OpenLiteSpeed. Given that ESI cannot be utilized, I’m not sure how to manage this effectively.
In my project, the admin bar is included in the layout.blade.php file as follows:
@if($is_admin)
    @include('themes.diamond.partials.admin_menu.toolbar',['route'=>$route])
@elseif($is_editor)
    @include('themes.diamond.partials.admin_menu.editor_toolbar',['route'=>$route])
@endif

Here are my main questions:
How can I configure LiteSpeed LSCACHE in Laravel to serve different cache versions for authenticated and unauthenticated users? Is there a way to exclude specific components, like the admin bar, from being cached without using ESI or AJAX? Any guidance or resources on this would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried set up rules in LiteSpeed to not cache content for users with specific cookies (like Laravel's session cookie) or when certain request headers are present?

I set guest_only to true in the config/lscache.php file. LiteSpeed does not cache for logged-in users, but when a visitor's page is cached, it appears for logged-in users. This is the default behavior of LiteSpeed, and it can be addressed using ESI. With ESI, LiteSpeed cache is disabled for certain parts of the page. However, ESI is a paid feature. In WordPress, this issue can be prevented without using ESI, but I couldn't find any resources on how to do this in other platforms.
